# Avoid downloading to filesystem hundreds of images, but avoid hotlinking also

Tags: php, javascript

I have an affiliate site which gets products from 10's of merchants in my niche and compares them, filters them. Some products have reviews, other just user comments, etc.

Lately, google started to penalize affiliate sites, and many of my competing sites dropped heavily in the last year.

So I am trying to prevent this, and I know it's a machine which analyzes my site at the end.

**One step I want to take is not hotlink the images provided by the merchants.**

I cannot save them all to the filesystem since they are so many, so I am thinking of another thing. This is where I need your opinion:

Instead of having:

```
<a href="hotlinkedMerchantImage.html">Product Image</a>
```

I would have something like this:

```
<a href="myimage.php">My image</a>
```

The php script would pull the merchant image, load it temporarily, and serve it to the user, until he closes the browser.

This would be a blend of php and javascript I believe, but I am not sure it will serve my purpose.

**If it were you, how would you do this? How would you avoid downloading hundreds of images to the filesystem and not hotlink**

Comment: Proxying all the images would give you a big bandwidth bill and be rather slow.

Comment: _I cannot save them all [merchant images] to the filesystem since they are so many_ - I wonder if you just need to go ahead with this. When you remove a product from your site, delete the associated images. Why not try downloading the images for all of your products on a non-live server, and see how much disk space it needs? Be careful not to overload your merchants' servers - put a small delay between fetches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way to pretend it's not hotlinked and is instead served from your domain would be to have a script that takes a URL to an image as a parameter and simply loads and streams it directly. This way it would look like it's being served from your server.

However, trying to avoid/exploit Google's algorithms is generally a good way to get your website completely removed from the index altogether and not just penalized. Something to keep in mind.

Comment: You are very right, this is why I am concerned - safest way would be to save the images to filesystem - though there is the performance concern